# ExifInterface UTF-8 support

Tags: android, image-processing, utf-8, exif

I am trying to write TAMIL characters in Exif tags, it writes without any error/warning,

```
    try{
        ExifInterface exifInterface  = new ExifInterface(someFile.getPath());
        String text="ENGLISHதமிழ்";
        exifInterface.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_IMAGE_DESCRIPTION,text);
        exifInterface.saveAttributes();
    }
```

But it writes TAMIL characters as **ENGLISH???????????????**,

I tried applying Unicode character conversions too.

```
    try{
        ExifInterface exifInterface  = new ExifInterface(someFile.getPath());
        String text="ENGLISHதமிழ்";
        text = UnicodeUtil.unicode2tsc(text);
        exifInterface.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_IMAGE_DESCRIPTION,text);
        exifInterface.saveAttributes();
    }
```

Any solution to write Unicode characters in meta data.

Comment: Android's ExifInterface is poor, it converts strings to ASCII. It seems ExifInterface doesn't like unicode completely - just study the source code.

Answer (score 3):

Tag "ImageDescription" only support ASCII charset.

As an alternative, you can use Tag "UserComment", it support Unicode charset.

Unfortunately，Android Jetpack's ExifInterface lib did not support use Unicode charset to write "UserComment" tag.

So you should do it yourself, or try this lib:

https://github.com/ddyos/UnicodeExifInterface