# Xamarin Android - Trouble with adding EXIF metadata for accented characters

Tags: android, .net, xamarin, mobile, xamarin.android

I'd like to ask you for a hand because I'm in a technical impasse on a Mobile project in Xamarin Android (not Forms nor IOS).

Indeed, in my application, I take a picture via the application and just before sending it to my Blob Storage (on Azure), I modify the file by adding metadata via EXIF (more precisely using the ExifInterface object).

The problem I'm having is that the special characters in my properties (even the COMMENT tag) are replaced by question marks :(
On my side, it is not possible to work without the special characters because my application is used all over the world (Vietnam, Morocco, Egypt or Canada).

The ExifInterface we use is the one from android.media, we tried with the one from the androidx.media version but the result is the same.
We also considered using XMP to add our metadata but a limitation of the Xamarin framework prevents us from doing this (absence of the system.windows.media.imaging library which blocks bitmap manipulation).
We are totally looking for REX or a lead :)

Thanks to you for your time

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49023824/exifinterface-utf-8-support

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I've already come across this topic, the only answer says that the COMMENT tag undestand unicode but I see that this is not true in my solution

Comment: that's not what it says.  "Android Jetpack's ExifInterface lib did not support use Unicode" and it suggests using an alternate library.

Comment: Oh my bad, totally my fault :s
Thanks, i will try to find a NuGET that can do the job :(